# ReflectionException - Function () does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, framework, routing

les agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme!
He intentado encontrar el error sin éxito, aunque todo parece estar correcto.
Estoy trabajando con Laravel 8.

Tengo en mi clase ItemController:

```
public function destroy(Item $item) {
  $item->delete();
  return redirect()->route('item-list', $item);
}
```

En mis rutas:

```
Route::delete('destroy/{item}', [ItemController::class], 'destroy')->name('items.delete');
```

Y en mi formulario:

```
    <form action="{{route('items.delete', $item)}}" method="POST">
      @csrf
      @method('delete')
      <button type="submit">Eliminar</button>
    </form>
```

El error que me arroja es:

```
ReflectionException
Function () does not exist
http://midominio.com/destroy/57
```

Si elimino @method('delete') del form, me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.
```

Agradezco desde ya cualquier pista que puedan darme.

Answer (score 4):

Para quien haya tenido el mismo problema!

El error estaba en:
`[ItemController::class], 'destroy')`
que debería decir:
`[ItemController::class, 'destroy')]`

Error de principiante :)

Comment: jajajaja, me paso a mi, pase como 1 hora perdida buscando el error... Hay no, aun me falta mucho por caminar... Gracias, son unos Crack